# If I build a new CPU, what should the BIOS contain?(Read details)

Tags: assembly, cpu, hardware, bios

I am trying to build a CPU from scratch (from Nor gates) in an emulator first, then on breadboard.

Just trying to understand how things work.

Now, as my CPU will be new, how would I instruct an OS, say arch linux to work with it?

What role the BIOS will play?
Will I have to write a BIOS which contains an assembler in it?

Do I need to write some program on the OS too?

So that, it starts to communicate to with my CPU.

[P.S]: I am a programmer, so pretty much have idea on how things move till assembly level.

Just want to know how the hardware level works beyond Assembly.

Or in other words, what was written on BIOS for the first ever computer?

How did it bootstrap?

Comment: If you're asking about old computers, try https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/ .  [BIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS)'s were created for the PC industry to smooth over differences.  You don't need one to boot a computer.  The PDP-8, for example, had a front panel with toggle switches that was used to toggle in about 15 instructions that would read paper tape.  The paper tape program would know how to read the disc and then the disc would have the operating system.

Comment: When porting an operating system to a new architecture, *extensive* rewrites of low-level code have to be done. This is also too many questions in one question, and most of them are too broad.

Comment: If it implements an existing ISA that Linux has been ported to (for example MIPS or RISC-V are simpler to implement than most), then in theory Linux might run on it if your board has I/O devices that Linux has drivers for. (If not then you have a lot of kernel coding work to do.)  You might just put a kernel image into ROM or something.  Linux will expect to talk to hardware directly, not make BIOS calls, so you don't really need an actual BIOS, just some code in ROM to set up the machine and load a kernel image.  Like a bootloader that works by talking to hardware directly, not to any "BIOS".

Comment: To give a short answer: your breadboard CPU will not be able to run Arch Linux and you will not need a BIOS.  The BIOS is an implementation detail of the PC and not needed if you don't build a PC.  There's also no need to put an assembler into the machine.  You can assemble code by hand and then later write an assembler.

Comment: If you want to port linux, you'll need C compiler for your architecture.

Comment: Start with this https://www.nand2tetris.org as exercise, it teaches to build a computer from NAND gates (you can do it with NOR). Look at the showcases how far people brought it. To your question: Linux is not the simplest operating system to start with as it needs a MMU Memory Management Unit. That is why Linux does not run on small microcontrollers

Comment: @Sebastian, oh I see. Then, I had a bad idea of Linux. I thought Linux can run on micro systems. In fact, I know at least  2 controllers that run linux and is hosted within a real hardware. I think, I need to read more on this side of the story.

Comment: @Sebastian, yes I went through the first part in Coursera and saw how Assembler works. My confusion started from there actually. So, if OS has to run on a CPU architecture, it also needs to send machine code instructions. So, I thought of fully starting from scratch with different approach.

Comment: The BIOS provides some early drivers to make the hardware usable, it tests and initializes the system and searches the drives for an operating system.

Comment: @Sebastian and then after that, it passes control over to OS which has some machine code in it? And from there, it gradually moves upwards, is it?

Comment: If you want to create a running computer, either make a very very  simple microcontroller with some ICs, or implement it in a FPGA. There are lots of people creating a vintage game console from scratch for the fun of it.

Comment: Everything which runs on a computer has machine code in it. If you want to run a (non machine-code) script, actually an interpreter written in machine code is executing the script. To make it more easy to create machine code, there are compilers from languages like C or C++.

Comment: @Sebastian, thank you very much for all the information and help. It really cleared most of my missing links. Can you please write all your comments in an answer for future readers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can recommend you "The Fabric of Computing" article series: https://jeelabs.org/202x/tfoc/

There will be some initial code in every computer, but what it does is entirely up to you! In embedded, the "bios" is the complete application.

Going straight from soldering gates is a long and arduous way. I am doing CPU design on FPGAs, and I am contributor in a course that takes you from the first steps in logic to a full RISC-V CPU with compiled C programs:

https://github.com/BrunoLevy/learn-fpga

Good luck! With FPGAs, it is actually possible to reach booting Linux with a custom design:

https://github.com/enjoy-digital/litex

Answer (score 2):

> Just trying to understand how things work.

How things work is that a CPU is just one piece of a system. Without RAM it's useless, without some form of persistent storage it's useless, and without some kind of IO to talk to the outside world (e.g. a serial port maybe) it's useless.

> What role the BIOS will play?

"BIOS" (or more correctly, some kind of ROM used when the system is turned on) plays the role of "storage" - a way for the CPU to obtain executable code  that's needed to initialize other storage devices and load more executable code.

For your "NOR gates spread across hundreds of breadboards" you'll probably end up putting a very minimal "OS" directly in the ROM so that you don't have to worry about providing additional persistent storage; and with about 10 years of dedication you might eventually see your minimal OS work 3 times (before getting tired of "which wire is having a bad connection this week?" continual breakage).

For some perspective; 1 bit of RAM will cost you 4 NOR gates, so a measly 512 bytes of RAM will cost you 16384 NOR gates (more for row/column select logic, etc). That works out to over 4000 "74LS02 Quadruple Two Input NOR Gate" chips. If you can pack 40 of these chips on a breadboard then you're looking at about 100 breadboards just to end up with not enough RAM to run any OS.

Comment: I meant the whole CPU - RAM combination by the way. On the calculation, that's a good estimate. Hmm, that's fine. I won't go for breadboard. But, yeah can try on logisim.

Answer (score 1):

Operating systems can be very very simple — if you just want the system to boot and do a few things like devices and threads but don't want all the protections and features of a full-fledged operating system.

All you really need is the ability to respond to interrupts and signal the user level software that data is ready (buffering input) or the device is ready, and, sort of the reverse, that user level software can indicate (e.g. via syscalls) data it wants to send to devices (buffered output) or obtain from them.  That can be had with a few hundred lines of assembly for an interrupt handler, a mini os.

But there are many systems that don't even have that level of sophistication.  Some program micro controllers to simply run one program, without interrupts, they have one main event loop that continuously checks for button presses or other.